# Front end hasn't crashed yet, but is unresponsive. Is there any way to get my unsaved definitions?

Tags: front-end

The front-end isn't responding, the only thing I can do is force quit it. Essentially, I can select any window (I have a few open), and I can move the windows, but I can't scroll or anything.  There is a "Save As" dialog box open, that I opened when I saw things were going south.  But I can't do anything with that window, and when I try to close it, Ubuntu gives me the message that it isn't responding, would you like to Force Quit it? And I know if I do that, then all of Mathematica shuts down.

But I have a few key things I would like to have access to first.  Is there any way of accessing them?  Is there a text file somewhere in my base directory (linux) where all of the `In[]` are stored?

I essentially want what Chrome does, saying "It looks like you didn't shut down properly, would you like to restore your tabs?"

Comment: I've never found anything that works -- sorry.

Comment: You can enable notebook auto-save or keep a history of inputs and outputs. But you need to decide to do this before a problem arises. Now, it's too late, I think. The only way could be to start a debugger and read the process memory directly--but whether you can interpret what you find is another question.

Comment: Can you screenshot it?

Comment: I can't screenshot, as I'm home from work now. @Oleksandr, I would love to know how to keep an input history. I know this is my fault for not saving as I go, but my workflow is to constantly open new notebooks and try things until I have the functions how I want them, then to consolidate and save.

Comment: Under Windows force-closing the Kernel from the Task manager usually unfreezes the FrontEnd.

Comment: I can confirm that alexey's solution often helps. You lose all definitions in the kernel, but you can save your text.

Comment: Absolutely it does help to quit the kernel, but I tried that here, under Linux killing any instance of mathkernel or wolframkernel I see. I suspect there's no way out so I just spend a couple hours reproducing. Thanks for your help